# Плавный переход страницы

Tags: javascript, html

Вот есть такой **JS** код:

```
        var updownElem = document.getElementById('down');

    var pageYLabel = 0;

    updownElem.onclick = function() {
      var pageY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

      switch (this.className) {
        case 'down':
          pageYLabel = pageY;
          window.scrollTo(0, +500);
              t = setTimeout('up()',20);
          this.className = 'down';
      }
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы переход шел плавно до самого низа страницы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал:

```
        var t;
    function down() {
    if((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) < document.documentElement.scrollHeight) { 
    window.scrollBy(0,100); 
    time = setTimeout('down()',40);}
     else clearTimeout(time); 
     return false;
}
```